# How to prevent appCache from updating after refreshing the browser if the manifest file changes

Tags: javascript, html, cache-manifest

I want a user to update their web app themselves when they ready so that even if they refresh the browser and there is a change to the manifest file it won't update. Is this possible?

I have even tried to abort it inside the event handler without any luck:

```
var appCache = window.applicationCache;
appCache.addEventListener('downloading', function() {
    appCache.abort();
}, false);
appCache.addEventListener('checking', function() {
    appCache.abort();
}, false);
appCache.abort();
```

These event handlers do get called but it does not abort the process and still downloads the new files. Any way round this or I am missing something perhaps?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177571/html-5-appcache-user-controlled-updating

Comment: Thanks a lot n0m4d. I managed to get around this shortcoming of appCache going through the question you linked here. Using Cookies, although not ideal, is a key element to getting this flow to work

Comment: Great to hear that man! Feel free to mark this comment as useful by clicking the arrow that shows next to my comment =)